# IP address conflict

Tags: network-configuration

I have a modem/router combo with phone service, I also have more than one computer running on my network, last evening not to lone after I closed my browser and pulled me flash drive I noticed that my DELL displayed a window with an error stating that there was a conflict between the DELL and the ASUS machines. After doing some looking around in both machines I did find within my ASUS command prompt and the DELL event viewer they did in fact hold the same address. Is this due to the TOR browser? Does TOR configure the network within the modem/router, or is it individual? I had an online chat with my ISP. Simple fix, unplug the router for 10 seconds, shut down both machines before plugging back in, after power up the issue is resolved.

Comment: Tor does not change your network configuration. So it rather must an error with your initial configuration.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this due to the TOR browser? Does TOR configure the network within the modem/router, or is it individual?

No. Tor doesn't change your network configuration.